# Probability of longest run of 1s being k in a n_bit binary number?

Tags: probability, statistics, permutations

Given a n-bit binary number, what is the probability of the longest run of $1's$ in this number being $k$ while
$1\leq k\leq n$ and the probability of every bit being 0 or 1 is $0.5$.
My solution was that if the longest run is $k$ then by choosing $k$ bits from $n$ bits and setting all the other bits to zero, we will sure have what we want but I don't know how to include the parts where there are other ones too but they don't form the longest run.

Comment: Essentially you will have to divide the $0'$s from the $1's$ and do stars and bars in both. Do you know stars and bars? I mean, factor your string as $0^{k_1}1^{s_1}0^{k_2}1^{s_2}\cdots 0^{k_n},$ so you fix the number of consecutive 1's and 0's. It becomes a problem of compositions.

Comment: Sorry i didn't totally get it. I mean how can i still keep max run at k with that solution? @Phicar

Comment: You might find [this](http://www.csun.edu/~hcmth031/tlroh.pdf) helpful.

Comment: @Sara because this allows you, by principle of inclusion-exclusion to set the run of length k and set the other consecutive terms to have length less than k.

Comment: That was helpful thank you @phicar

Comment: @lulu how am i supposed to answer and get my 10 pts when you steal my thunder - <the rep whore>